# Check if tab exists and make it active; otherwise create it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm attempting to see if the tab 'http://google.com' exists.  If it does then I want to make it the active page.  Otherwise, the tab 'http://google.com' doesn't exist, and I want to create it.

backround.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse){
    chrome.tabs.create({'url': 'http://google.com'}, function(tab) {
        alert('Tab Created ' + tab.id);
        var oms = tab.id;
        chrome.tabs.update(oms, {url:"http://en.wikipedia.org"});
    });
});
```

This creates the webpage, gets the `tabid` and sets the `tabid` as a variable.

Comment: could not get chrome.tabs.update(oms, {selected: true}); to work

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I've edited your question to lead with the explanation of what you're trying to have happen.  I also added the [tag:google-chrome-extension] tag, since I only know that's what you're talking about because I have some experience making them.  But I'm not sure what Wikipedia has to do with your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current attempt seems to be trying to create a tab with Google, and then navigate it to Wikipedia.  This doesn’t agree with your initial paragraph.  Instead, I think you want something similar to the following:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse){
    chrome.tabs.query({'url': 'http://google.com'}, function(tabs) {
        if ( tabs.length > 0 ) {
            chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id,{'active':true});
        } else {
            chrome.tabs.create({'url':'http://google.com'});
        }
    });
});
```

Note that this won’t find http://www.google.com, or http://google.com/otherstuff.  You’ll probably want to use a [match pattern](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).

You commented having trouble with updating the tab to be `selected`.  The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update) says that `selected` is deprecated in favor of `highlighted`.  This also hints what else may have happened: a `highlighted` tab is not necessarily active (specifically, you can have several tabs `highlighted`).